# Could a hard-reference to WeakReference.get() object cause memory leak?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, memory-leaks, weak-references

We have, let's say, a very long thread:

```
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final WeakReference<Context> contextRef;

    private MyRunnable(Context leakable) {
        contextRef = new WeakReference<>(leakable);
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        Context context = contextRef.get();
        if (context == null) return;
        //VERY LONG TASK
        //Would hard referencing context gotten from WeakReference.get() leak memory?
        //Should contextRef be called each time context is needed?
    }
}


private void startThread() {
    new MyThread(this, new MyRunnable(this)).start();
}
```

The questions says all itself:

-Would hard referencing context gotten from WeakReference.get() leak memory?

-Should contextRef be called each time context is needed, in order to avoid leaking?

-The WeakReference.get() method calls a native method through JNI, would be get() method call expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would hard referencing context gotten from WeakReference.get() leak memory?

If an object is still being used, I wouldn't consider this a memory leak.  If you are retaining memory you don't need, this can be a problem.  You can clear/discard the string reference when you no longer need it.

Having a weak reference to an object doesn't change the behaviour of any strong reference.

> Should contextRef be called each time context is needed, in order to avoid leaking?

Only if you are ok with it disappearing while you do this.  If you need this to return the object (even before you call run()) you need to hold a string reference.

Note: your example, the first time you call `get()` it can return `null` but if it doesn't matter whether this runs at all, could you just not do it at all.

Comment: This question is a bit focused on Android. The GC in Android could reclaim memory by GC-ing the Context object so, if context object is hard referenced that wont be possible. That way, the object could be still used but also could be a problem. So, my question is if hard referencing WeakReference.get() result would avoid the GC to clear the object

Comment: @BamsBamx a strong reference always prevent an object being collected, no matter what else you do.

Comment: so, in this case: hard-referencing the WeakReference.get() result is the same as hard-referencing 'leakable' object passed in the MyRunnable constructor?

Comment: @BamsBamx the only difference using a WeakReference here instead of a strong reference, is that it might disappear before run() is called, but not while it is being called. Note: unless the GC runs, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @BamsBamx: you seem to have a wrong mindset shown by repeatedly saying “hard-referencing the WeakReference.get()”. You have a strong reference to an object, that’s all. Whether you have retrieved that object by calling `WeakReference.get()` or via any other way, is irrelevant. A strong reference is a strong reference.